# Транзакции MySQL

Tags: mysql

Необходимо совершить транзакцию в нескольких DML-запросах. В первом

```
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
```

, в следующем — сам запрос, и в последнем —

```
mysql> COMMIT
```

. Движок стоит InnoDB, `SET AUTOCOMMIT=0`, но почему-то всё равно каждый запрос сразу коммитится.

Comment: Как вы определили мгновенный коммит? Какой стоит уровень изоляции?

Comment: @Fike уровень изоляции - *REPEATABLE READ*. Открыл еще 1 вкладку phpmysql и сделал *SELECT \**

Comment: @voipp а команды тоже из майадмина пускаются?

Comment: @Fike да да

Comment: @Fike заработало! если уровень - *REPEATABLE READ*, то существует проблема фантомного чтения. При этом при старте транзакции ей доступна БД, актуальная именно на момент начала транзакции. Она, видимо хранит *snapshot* БД в памяти?
И вообще не понимаю, почему уровни так называются?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@voipp](/users/12796/voipp)](/users/12796/voipp), у вас нет транзакций, если вы пускаете команды по одной. При каждой загрузке страницы происходит переподключение к базе. Хотите увидеть все вживую - открывайте консоль.